# I have js error , saying Object [object Object] has no method 'countdown'

Tags: javascript

I have a website working fine in all browsers except IE. When I look at the console it says:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'countdown'
```

The website name is: http://www.rivalhost.com/

The problem is with menu. Please help me out of this guys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's no element with an id of `countdown` in the DOM, according to the console. Perhaps you misspelled it?

```
document.getElementById("countdown");
null
```

Comment: what is that countdown function is expecting a div or a input field or something else?

Comment: The offending code appears to be a line of JQuery attempting to reference an element with an id of `countdown`. Because JQuery can't find the element with that id, the rest of the code doesn't work.